# Weiner filter vs Analytical Linear optimal estimator

Tags: filters, estimation

I've been learning recently about estimation of stochastic processes in general, and linear estimation in particular.

On one hand I've seen the following estimation of $X[n]$ from $Y[n]$ -

$X_{opt} = \frac{COV(X[n],Y[n])}{VAR(Y[n])}(Y-E[Y]) + E[X]$

On the other hand we have Weiner filtering, for which -

$X_{opt-w}=h[n] * Y[n] \space\space;\space\space   H(e^{jw})=\frac{S_{XY}(w)}
{S_{YY}(w)} \space\space ; S_{XY},S_{YY}:= PSD \space\space; H(e^{jw})\leftrightarrow h[n]$

All in all, both claim to be **optimal linear estimation** of $X[n]$ from $Y[n]$, I've been playing with few examples where I could show that $X_{opt-w}=X_{opt}$, but couldn't really understand if that's always the case.

My questions are -
What is a good rule of thumb to prefer each one of them? Will i want to choose $X_{opt}$ only in the case that $E[X[n]],\space E[Y[n]] \ne 0$? When it applies that $X_{opt-w}=X_{opt}$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Dig into the math -- those are equivalent.  First, they pretty much have to me (there's only one optimum in the mean-squared sense), and second, if you can get past the tortured logic of using covariance in the first example instead of correlation, I think you'll find that the Fourier transform of the first equation gives you the derivation for $H\left(e^{j \omega}\right)$ in the second equation.

Comment: Can you point to the source texts, or at least clarify what is meant by $COV \left( X[n], Y[n] \right) / VAR \left ( Y[n] \right)$?  Are they doing a point-by-point divide, or some sort of a matrix division?